# how to align the dots horizontally under signature with the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, overleaf

Hello I am using overleaf to write my thesis but i am having hard time aligning the dots horizontally under the signature with the right side of the page. I would appreciate it if somebody knows how to do that. Thanks in advance.

```
\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{FINAL APPROVAL FOR THESIS}
\begin{center}
\textbf{FINAL APPROVAL FOR THESIS}
\end{center}

This thesis titled \textquotedblleft .. .. .. .." has been prepared and submitted by ... .. .. in partial fulfillment of the requirements in \textquotedblleft aa bb cc" for the Degree of Doctor of Philosophy (PhD) in Mathematics has been examined and approved on 12/08/2022. 
\\[2cm]
\begin{tabular}{lclp{3cm}}
 \textbf{\underline{Committee Members}} \qquad  \qquad             && \textbf{\underline{Title, Name and Surname}} & \textbf{\underline{Signature}} \\[1cm]
Supervisor  :&&aa bb &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&cc dd &\dotfill \\[0.3cm] 
Member      :&& aa bb         &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb     & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb   & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb        & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
\end{tabular}
\\[3cm]

\normalsize
\bigskip

\bigskip

\bigskip



$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\begin{array}{c}
\text{aa bb}\\
\text{Director of Graduate School of Sciences}%
\end{array}%
$
\normalsize
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Sorry, don't understand how a successcful "aligning (of) the dots horizontally under the signature with the right side of the page" would look like. Can you add a mockup sketch screenshot of your desired result, please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a preliminary analysis and solution, which also shows some potential problems.

Wrt. your code, unfortunately we miss the relevant preamble. So I put in some standard. As you can see in the screenshot, **the result varies** "a little" depending on font-size (shown), documentclass (not shown) and packages (unknown by now).

My major changes, see `% <<<` in code:

- used package geometry to show how space is used for the various pieces of content
- used 4 `\newcommand` macros to obtain a shorter table-entry
- removed excessive columns, and `\quadd`'s
- replaced your format-code by 3 `p{width}` statements
- aligned code for better readability (and failure prevention)

The 3 `p{width}`-statments would let you place left side per column, while the width determines, where the next column has to start. (I neglect the intercolum separation here.)

? Probably you'll clarify my question in the comments abot what your signiure alignement should look like ?

[image: showframe for 10pt and 12 pt fonts]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}% << fontsize 10 pt

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}    % <<< just to show the current settings


% ~~~ abbreviations, for better read-ability ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\first[1]{\textbf{\underline{#1}}}
\newcommand\firstcm[0]{\first{Committee Members}}
\newcommand\firsttns[0]{\first{Title, Name and Surname}}
\newcommand\firstsig[0]{\first{Signature}}

\begin{document}

My suggestion:

\begin{tabular}{p{4.6cm}p{4.8cm}p{2.6cm}}% <<< p starts left, for indicated widths
%\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \firstcm{}      & \firsttns{}       & \first{Signature} \\[1cm]
    Supervisor  :   & Sam, Ghost        &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
    Member      :   & Charly Chaplin    &\dotfill \\[0.3cm] 
    Member      :   & Lady Gaga         &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
    Member      :   &aa bb              & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
    Member      :   &aa bb              & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
    Member      :   &aa bb              & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
\end{tabular}
\\[3cm]


Your approach:

\begin{tabular}{lclp{3cm}}
 \textbf{\underline{Committee Members}} \qquad  \qquad && \textbf{\underline{Title, Name and Surname}} & \textbf{\underline{Signature}} \\[1cm]
Supervisor  :&&aa bb &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&cc dd &\dotfill \\[0.3cm] 
Member      :&& aa bb         &\dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb     & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb   & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
Member      :&&aa bb        & \dotfill \\[0.3cm]
\end{tabular}
\\[3cm]

\end{document}
```